# Failed to start Marketing Automation service

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, installation, certificate

I've an issue in installing `Sitecore 9.2` in a machine where Sitecore is getting installed for the first time. On the middle of the installation, I'm getting `Failed to start Marketing Automation service` error. Even the `XConnect` site is not loading. In the logs for MA, I'm getting Socket exception : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

1. Solr is running fine on HTTPS
2. Tried the PS commands to identify and move the corrupt certificates
3. Ran prerequisites - installation completed successfully
4. Ran installation through both SIA and PS Script

Any idea? Please assist. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sometime office security settings do not allow to browse the websites even the website hosted on your local machine. If this is the case, you should add you websites name in the exception list. You can do this by Internet properties windows. You can reach here by command "inetcpl.cpl"

Comment: Are you 100% your Sitecore license is up to date and valid?

Comment: @Jitendra, thanks. I've no idea about what I should do after opening internet properties.

Comment: @ChrisAuer, thanks. I've the latest licensed

Comment: Check the logs at [install folder]\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Logs

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I see this error, the issue is with the license.

The license needs to be:

- Up to date
- Valid Xml
- Includes the key `xDB.Base`. XDB.Base signifies that the license is valid for xDB.